# How to map repeating xml elements in Excel

Tags: excel, xml, xml-parsing

I'm dealing with a problem on how to map repeating xml elements, the moment I imported the XML below as an XML map in excel, I see only 1 for the 4 records i need "<club_LIST>" of course this doesn't produce the 4 entries in the output XML.
Any idea how can this be solved in Excel ?

I from Microsoft support:
Additionally, the contents of an XML mapping cannot be exported if the contents contain one of the following XML schema constructs:

List of lists     One list of items contains a second list of items.

Any way around you could suggest to produce the xml?

Here below the sample of my data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<PartnersProfile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance">
    <ID>10</ID>
    <NAME>Table 10</NAME>
    <Record>
      <PARTNER_ID>1</PARTNER_ID>
      <DESCRIPTION>customer</DESCRIPTION>
      <subscription>2004</subscription>
      <club_LIST>1</club_LIST>
      <club_LIST>4</club_LIST>
      <club_LIST>6</club_LIST>
      <club_LIST>9</club_LIST>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <PARTNER_ID>1</PARTNER_ID>
      <DESCRIPTION>customer</DESCRIPTION>
      <subscription>2004</subscription>
      <club_LIST>1</club_LIST>
      <club_LIST>4</club_LIST>
      <club_LIST>6</club_LIST>
      <club_LIST>9</club_LIST>
    </Record>
</PartnersProfile>
```

[image]

Comment: "Any idea how can this be solved in Excel ?": It can't. How would you store a list of lists structure in a two dimensional sheet like a spreadsheet? In other words: How would you show the list behind `club_LIST` in column `D` of the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Consider transforming the XML to an itemized version by each `club_LIST` with repeating values for ancestor elements. You can run the below XSLT 1.0 by many tools and programming languages including Perl (from your profile) or Excel VBA.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/PartnersProfile">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::club_LIST"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="club_LIST">
     <Record>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::PartnersProfile/*[name()!='Record']"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Record/*[name()!='club_LIST']"/>
       <club_LIST><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></club_LIST>
     </Record>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NqjwkV)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue as you with this and found a workaround for this.

So basically in the XML map you define the <club_LIST> tag as follows

`<club_LIST>bla bla bla</club_LIST>`
`<club_LIST1>bla bla bla</club_LIST1>`
`<club_LIST2>bla bla bla</club_LIST2>`

this way when you import the map to the excel you will be able to map it to 3 columns and after export you open the exported file in notepad++ which has a great functionality "Find and replace" (shortcut ctrl/cmd + f) and you just instantly change tags

`<club_LIST1> </club_LIST1> <club_LIST2> </club_LIST2>`
to unnumbered ones.